# ckeditor undefined message after image upload

Tags: laravel-5, ckeditor4.x

I integrate uploadImage plugin to the CkEditor 4.

When i drag an image into the editor it get's uploaded fine.

I see the image on a folder in my server.

But in the editor i see a red message "undefined"

(Can't attach screen capture here so, https://uploads.disquscdn.com/images/b65f38b906cfb8b914a3d6476a40a6a4805c534e0bedfbe1039f838bbe4272a8.png)

and this is the json I'm sending in response from the server

```js
{
  "upload":1,
  "fileName":"15292215661489102869.png",
  "url":"\/images\/editor\/15292215661489102869.png"
  }
```

I'm using Laravel 5.3 as backend.

I already try to concatenate the base url, and urlencode that.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give to me

Comment: I just check that i was sending upload instead of uploaded in the response

Answer (score 1):

The problema was in the json response.

The key "upload" should be "uploaded", this cause a failed response on the client side